# VSCode's Find all references/Go to definition does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo

I have:

- mono repository, more projects inside
- js/ts, react

1. When **Find all references** is tried on react component (I suppose on anything) that is imported in another project inside monorepo, it starts finding references.
2. **Initializing JS/TS language features** starts - from Typescript and Javascript Language Features built-in extension.
3. It takes about 2 minutes (depends on project size)
4. After that references outside project/folder are not found
5. During that process I cannot use **Go to definition**

I have also solution and will be written in answer below to help other folks (maybe my future me :D) to not waste halfday as I did on this ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to VSCode settings (Mac -> CMD + ,)
2. Find Max TS Server Memory and raise it to 8000 MB (might be more or less, depends on your project size)
   [image]

Enjoy charm working :)

Explanation:
I suppose tsserver seemlessly crashed down once it hit max memory during indexing whole project.

Comment: How can we know if tsserver has crashed?